# How to create modern program without shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl

I've created a program that uses old functions(vertexpointer), and I want to make it faster with modern functions.
I think that I should create a pure, new one, but I thought I can ask this question here before I create a new one.
I tried to substitute one of the drawing functions, and the others went wrong too!

the init function:

```
glGenBuffers(10,vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(float)*vertSize,vert,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(float)*normalsSize,normals,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(pSlot);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(nSlot);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(pSlot,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(nSlot,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
```

I have no idea about the drawing...

I should use these:

```
glBindAttribLocation(prog, pSlot, "inVer");
glBindAttribLocation(prog, nSlot, "inNorm");
```

but it takes a `prog` parameter.

The problem is that I should rewrite the whole program if I use shaders, if I'm wrong, tell me, how to create shaders without creating uniforms for projection matrix, modelview matrix, and use the matrix stack directly, please.

So what's the newest thing that I should use with only creating init func changing drawing func, but not using shaders?
If this is avialable, what is the value of pSlot and nSlot? (I thought 0 and 2, because the old gl_Vertex and gl_normal (or something like that) in shaders uses these numbers)

Comment: I prefer using glGetAttribLocation Note: Don’t forget to link the program after binding the location to the attribute More Details:
http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/attribute-variables/

Comment: In modern OpenGL you'll have to implement shaders. There's no way around it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm trying to ignore the shaders. :)

Comment: I know, but not THAT modern openGL, a bit less modern. If it's absolutely unignorable, then what's the newest openGL what doesn't has to use that?

Comment: Its impossible, because the function give you the location from a shader. No shader = no location ;)

Comment: Well, if all you want is not using immediate mode, but Vertex Arrays, then you can't hardly tell this modern OpenGL. Vertex Arrays have been available for well over 15 years now. If you want to use generic vertex attributes, then you also must tell OpenGL how to process those attributes, which means writing a shader. And the later would be modern.

Comment: @radl: The term "modern OpenGL" generally means "core profile OpenGL 3.1+". So what are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're ignoring shaders, then you're stuck with the pre-3.0 vertex attributes (position, color, normal, texcoords, color index). You're supposed to use `glVertexPointer`, `glColorPointer`, `glNormalPointer` and the family, not the generic `glVertexAttribPointer`. There's no need for you to use `glBindAttribLocation` since generic (numbered) attributes are for shaders.

You're already using buffer objects, which is very good for performance.

The drawing functions (glDrawArrays*, gl(Multi)DrawElements*) look the same for fixed function and . The compatibility profile should let you get away with the fixed function and still use GL3 features like instancing.

Why do that? I have no idea; shaders simplify so much...

Comment: Thanks! I thought I can modernize my program a bit, with small changes. I would have to throw out matrix stack, and so many thing...

Comment: What exactly do you want to modernize about your program, if you're OK with using fixed function?

Comment: I want to copy to GPU the data in the beginning of the program.

Comment: I'm asking "what", not "why". What is faster? Which parts of the API? For example vertex buffer objects are faster than client-side vertex arrays, but you're already using them

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood, but now fixed.

Comment: I'm not using it, it's the not working code.

Answer (score 3):

I thought someone else would give the official answer.But here it is:

**No , you can't use modern (programmable) OpenGL without shaders.**